# How can I use kotlin.test with an Android project?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlintest

When I search for what I wrote on the title the internet is completely full of results about using JUnit, JUnit5, Mockito, TestNG and whatnot.

I went over [the official docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/jvm-test-using-junit.html#create-a-test) and they provide a sample with the JVM.

I went ahead and gave it a try and as soon as I add

```
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

to my `build.gradle` another plugin breaks with:

> Caused by: org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject$CustomMessageMissingMethodException: Could not find method test() for arguments [build_dufjov4kr7mc23edqwrf6trov$_run_closure1@6a819f87] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

How do I get past that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That `test` block seems optional.

Just add the following dependencies:

```
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
testImplementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test'
testImplementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit'
```

Then, in your tests, pick the correct imports, ie. `import kotlin.test.assertEquals`

Seems like the test block below is **NOT** necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Please see the [Kotlin Docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/jvm-test-using-junit.html#add-the-code-to-test-it) on how to set-up *Jetbrains Kotlin Test JUnit* on `Intellij` using *Kotlin DSL*.

Using this approach you need to do the following on `Android Studio`:

**Step 1 - Add this line to your dependencies:** i.e. inside `build.gradle.kts` **`(app-level)`** file

```
dependencies { 
...

testImplementation(kotlin("test"))
...

}
```

**Step 2 (Optional)- Add the test task block** i.e. inside `build.gradle(.kts)` **`(project-level)`** file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration ...

    plugins {
        id("com.android.application") apply false
        ....
    }
    
    // add this block on project-level build.gradle.kts
    tasks.withType<Test> {

        useJUnitPlatform()

    }
```

You can also try this dependency using the latest Kotlin Version (in Dec. 2023 it was **`1.9.10`**)

```
testImplementation ("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit:1.9.10")
```

This is what worked out for me.